# Exiting a calling sub from the called function

Tags: vba

Is it possible to exit a subA from **inside** subB, that was called by subA?

```
public subA()
    call subB()
end sub

subB()
    If true then
        'exit subA
    end if
    'continue
end sub
```

If this is not possible, what is the best way do this?
I have searched this site but all the similar questions have answers that solve the specific problem that the other ''ask''ers had. They were not suitable for me.

Comment: two suggestions, 1st do your logic test before calling subB and exit.  2nd chnge subB to a function that returns a boolean, test on the return and exit the sub.

Comment: I am aware of these two ways. My question is: What is the **best** way. I know that usually it makes sense to put everything a function is supposed to do **inside** the function, so that anyone who wants to use the function doesn't have to know about the implementation. besides the whole point of subB is the logic test. It does a few of them.

Comment: If part of the point of subB is to impact the operation of SubA, then of course you can't use subB without understanding the implementation of SubA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `subB` a function and use the return value to tell `subA` to exit:

```
public subA()
    if not subB() then
        Exit Sub   ' <--- new
    end if
end sub

function subB() as boolean
' returns True on success, False on failure.
    If <<some condition for exiting subA>> Then
        subB = False   '<--- new - cause subA to exit
        Exit Function
    end if
    'continue
    subB = True  '<--- new - tell subA it doesn't need to exit
End Function
```

**Edit**: The *best* way is the one that is the most readable and maintainable in the context of your particular code.  Use what makes sense - there is no hard rule.  For example:

- You could incorporate `subB` into `subA`; that way you wouldn't have a nested-exit problem.
- You could use `Err.Raise` in `subB` and `On Error` in the *caller* of `subA`.  However, that mixes error-handling with normal flow of control, which often reduces maintainability.